# Picking out peaks that fit a pattern

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got data with time (seconds) on the x axis and intensity (in relative fluorescent units, or rfu) on the y-axis. It's generated by watching fragments of DNA pass a camera - the bigger the DNA fragment the bigger the time. There are 23 fragments of known size (in DNA base pair units, bp), and therefore there should be 23 peaks. As I know the size of the DNA fragments in bp, I want to recalibrate the x-axis from time (seconds) to base pairs (bp) using a linear model.

Unfortunately there is quite a lot of noise in the data that produces spurious peaks. The only way to confidently tell the true ones from the false ones is that the false ones don't fit the expected pattern in DNA base pairs.

I've provided data from one sample at this link in a data frame called demo. Unfortunately it's too large to paste below.

https://1drv.ms/t/s!AvBi5ipmBYfrhf0v_kvWuN2foLyBgg?e=RWfdXZ

I can pick out all the peaks as follows.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
ggplot(demo, aes(x=time, y=rfu)) +
geom_line(size=0.1) +
stat_peaks(col = "red", span=5, ignore_threshold=0.1) +
theme_bw()
```

[image]

However, these are the expected DNA fragment sizes (in bp):

```
ladder <- c(50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 475, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000)
```

And here is a plot with the correct peaks picked out:

[image]

Is there any way to get a peak finder such as stat_peak or ggpmisc:::find_peaks to take an pattern of peaks into account when selecting peaks to achieve the second plot??

Addendum:
The false peaks may be within the same rfu range as the true peaks, so peak height can't be used to exclude them (see example from a different sample below)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, yes it really is noise - it's bleed through from one of the other 4 channels. I didn't share that data with you as I thought it would overcomplicate the issue. I've removed the noise as best possible, but can't get rid of entirely. I can manually select the peaks, but it's v painful. I was hoping a peak caller might already have a solution, but I suppose the method would include iteratively calling 23 peaks (maybe at random??) and then checking the linear model against the expected pattern to find the best fit??

Comment: Have you searched for at [Bioconductor](https://www.bioconductor.org/)?

Comment: @tjebo the time varies from run to run, so isn't reliable. That said, there should always be a couple of hundred seconds between peaks at least.

Comment: @Henrik there's an R package called Fragman that achieves this, but it's very clunky and requires a lot of input. I've got every step of the up and downstream analysis that Fragman does sorted, except for this one step

Comment: Mike, your bounty is looking for an answer from a reputable source - Jon is very reputable...:) What, in your opinion, does not work / is lacking in his answer?

Comment: Take a look at ```anomalize``` package. Seems like you need to identify anomalies in time series.

Comment: Thank you, it looks like anomalies might be able to help. I'm trying to get it working, but am having trouble. Do you have experience with anomalize? I've tried converting time from seconds to date time using lubridate and looking at the trend with time_decompose. I've also tried converting rfu into a time series vector and using iqr_outliers.

Comment: @tjebo Jon's answer is closest so far, but doesn't solve the problem. It requires that the anomalous peaks have a height different to the true peaks. My question was distinguishing false peaks by the x value (time), rather than y value (rfu)

Comment: ok - after your 2nd example (which is very useful, thanks for adding this) - does it mean that the peaks are expected to be always *more or less* in a relatively similar time distance to one another?

Comment: Do you have a sense of how precisely the runs "should be consistent?" Do they just have different starting positions (as we might expect from a digital process), or also different speeds (which might happen in a mechanical process with different weights/resistance), or is there also idiosyncratic acceleration (such as in a manual process)? Those involve progressively more parameters to fit.

Comment: @JonSpring thanks for getting stuck into this, much appreciated. Sounds like more info about the process may help. The 23 DNA fragments are a standard that is from a consistent source and does not change. They are loaded on a machine that injects them into a capillary, applies a current to move them along, and they pass a camera which records the fluorescence in rfu. Therefore ...

Comment: 1) Starting positions will be consistent. 2) Speeds can differ (i.e. the 16th peak could appear anywhere from 7400-7700 seconds for eg). 3) There should not be idiosyncratic acceleration (there is no manual involvement in loading the DNA fragments into the capillary or applying the current). I've included a large number of demo samples (581!) in the csv here in case helpful for seeing the variability: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvBi5ipmBYfrhoEYSw2MG9eT2MVlXw?e=cjnvZQ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the given data, we can isolate the peaks by looking for local maxima between 1000 to 6000. This identifies the 23 peaks.

I used the `slider` package to identify the maximum value within a 21 bp (time - 10 to time +10) range, and then excluded points outside the `rfu` range of 1000-6000 or which matched the point prior.

```
library(tidyverse); library(slider)
demo %>%
  mutate(peak = rfu == slider::slide(
    rfu, max, .before = 10, .after = 10) & 
      rfu > 1000 & rfu < 6000 & rfu != lag(rfu)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time, rfu, color = peak, alpha = peak)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

I explored whether it might be possible to find a brute-force "best fit", which might make this more automatic and robust to noise that is within the same ranges as the underlying signals. I'm sure it's possible, but it's more difficult than I expected, since the "time stretch" varies across the range, so a simple offset + scaling model with two parameters won't suffice. The "time stretch" between the ladder and the data varies gradually from a little over 10x (ie the 25 dif from 50 to 75 on ladder translates to 253 dif in data 1578 to 1831) at the start, to under 5x at the end.

In this case, it looks like a quadratic fit would probably do well, but that might not translate to other data that is time-distorted differently.

[image]

[image]

If the distortion were totally uniform between runs, it might be more useful to define the ladder with the distortion built-in, like the "ladder_scaled" column below. Then the question would be reduced to finding a single offset value with best fit to the data, in the case of your example +1528.

```
ladder_scaled <- tibble::tribble(
      ~ladder, ~ladder_scaled,
   50 ,          50,
   75 ,         303,
  100 ,         557,
  125 ,         811,
  150 ,        1068,
  200 ,        1580,
  250 ,        2104,
  300 ,        2630,
  350 ,        3159,
  400 ,        3684,
  450 ,        4204,
  475 ,        4451,
  500 ,        4705,
  550 ,        5203,
  600 ,        5683,
  650 ,        6143,
  700 ,        6574,
  750 ,        6983,
  800 ,        7357,
  850 ,        7701,
  900 ,        8010,
  950 ,        8283,
  1000,         8523
  )
```

If we can rely on consistent time alignment between runs, we can solve for the timing offset which provides the best alignment with the data, even if there are overlapping noisy peaks within our data. One tricky thing about this particular example is that the ladder "signature" is not very unique -- the spacing is similar between most steps on the ladder, so you get a decent fit in most lost functions even if you're offset by one or two "steps" of the ladder.

Here's one approach where I brute force the fit on a bunch of offset values. I am relying on the assumption (perhaps unwarranted) that the ladder has a consistent time length, and the only variable to solve for is time offset. I believe the problem becomes exponentially more difficult if this cannot be assumed.

To start with, I use a much wider range of plausible values which include 6 noisy peaks in addition to the 23 real ones:

```
demo %>%
  mutate(peak = rfu == slider::slide(
    rfu, max, .before = 10, .after = 10) & 
      rfu > 500 & rfu < 30000 & rfu != lag(rfu)) -> demo_labels
# includes 29 "peaks": 23 real + 6 noisy
```

Then I cross with a range of possible offsets from 0:5000, and fuzzy join each peak to the possible ladder peaks that are within 200 time units. For each possible offset and peak, I pick the closest fit, and then for each possible offset, I pick the 23 closest fits. Finally, I plot the worst alignment for each offset value. This shows that in the original data, an offset of around 1528 provides the best fit. But a difficult thing about this particular "ladder signature" is that an offset of 1976, ~450 higher,  doesn't look tremendously worse by this measure, even though it's definitely wrong. So it probably will take some more domain knowledge to identify a better function than "worst fit" for picking good matches.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
demo_labels %>%
  filter(peak) %>%
  crossing(offset = seq(0, 5000, by = 2)) %>%
  mutate(time_adj = time - offset) %>%
  distance_left_join(ladder_scaled, 
                  by = c("time_adj" = "ladder_scaled"),
                  max_dist = 200) %>%
  mutate(time_error = time_adj - ladder_scaled) %>% 
  group_by(offset, time_adj) %>%
  slice_min(abs(time_error)) %>%
  group_by(offset) %>%
  slice_min(abs(time_error), n = 23) %>%  ### pick the 23 best fits %>%
  summarise(worst_error = max(abs(time_error)),
            matching_peaks = n()) %>%
  arrange(worst_error) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(offset, worst_error, alpha = matching_peaks == 23)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm working through your answer now and will get back to you more fully. However, it may be helpful to mention that the time distortion should be consistent for different runs - in case that helps you with the quadratic fit. Would you be able to share your 10X time scaling solution too? I can also share data from other samples if helpful?

Comment: PS I've just added an addendum above - the false peaks can be the same height in rfu as the true ones, so size can't reliably be used to exclude them

Comment: Does it that the false peaks rarely appear >5000 seconds? Could you identify the time fit using peaks >5000 seconds and then use that to look for peaks in a narrow window with slider or something similar?

Comment: This should read "does it help that ..."

Comment: First pass this seems to work very well on the single demo data provided. I've also shared data from 581 other samples in the csv file here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvBi5ipmBYfrhoEYSw2MG9eT2MVlXw?e=cjnvZQ. I'm going to have a go with your solution on some other samples and will let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

Before plotting, doing some data manipulation to pull out the maximum value for each of the 23 DNA fragment groups with base R *`max`* function, and adding the max plot with additional geom_ layer for the max values.

Here is small reprex example that plots the max value for each group with "red".

```
data.frame(x = 1:9) %>% 
     mutate(y = rep(LETTERS[1:3], c(3, 3, 3) )) %>% 
     group_by(y) %>% 
     mutate(max = max(x), .groups = "drop") %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = y, y = x)) + 
     geom_point() + 
     geom_point(aes(x = y, y = max), col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I believe this just finds the tallest peak (y) at each point along the x axis. What I need to do is only pick out peaks which fit a pattern along the x-axis, regardless of the height on the y-axis. You'll notice that the DNA fragments in the 'ladder' are 25-50 bp apart, and that's the pattern I'd like to use for selecting peaks on my x-axis. However, the x-axis is in a different unit (time).

Comment: Can you share small sample reproducible data?

Comment: There’s a sample here: https://1drv.ms/t/s!AvBi5ipmBYfrhf0v_kvWuN2foLyBgg?e=RWfdXZ

Comment: The peaks aren't happening in a regular interval. Is it possible  you can add a third variable to label the 23 fragments in the data?

Comment: What do you mean by a third variable?

Comment: Or, if the time interval between picks was equal, we can extract the picks with data manipulation. On this case the time interval is diffrent.

Comment: The time interval between peaks may not be identical, but it is known and consistent (25 or 50 bp), so would that help pick up the pattern somehow?

Comment: I was able to id most, but not all, picks using the higher bunched up rfu values to id patterns and  slice the data to 23 fragments. But because the picks do not have consistent time frequency, I am unable to get ALL picks, due to overlaps during slicing. If labeling the 23 fragments with additional column is possible, it would help greatly. Or, If that isn't possible, having the time variable with equal intervals for each fragment is another option. (Disclaimer: I don't have the expertise in your experiment, if what I am suggesting doesn't make sense, please understand.)

Comment: This is starting to get there I feel. When I tried to do this I started with the larger fragments to, as there's usually less noise >5000s, so less spurious peaks. How did you do pattern recognition on these larger peaks? I'm still not following what you mean by labelling peaks with an additional column. The data is generated by a machine and I need this algorithm to label the peaks by distinguishing them from the noise using the expected peak pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to id each pick for the 18 fragments. The code starts the time greater than 3000 seconds and removes the noise bellow 2000 rfu. The code id and gives pattern for each fragment, then extract the picks (maxs) for each fragmen.  Here are the codes and the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)
# identify/build pattern for each fragment (1,2,0)
df_1 <-      
demo %>% 
        # remove the noise
        filter(time > 3000, rfu >= 2000) %>%  
        mutate(frag = ifelse(rfu >= 2900, 1, 0),
               lbl = ifelse(frag == 0, 1, 2))  %>% 
        as_tibble() %>% 
        mutate(lbl_z = lag(frag)) 

# grab the repeat pattern and  add incrmental unique labels        
df_2 <-      
df_1 %>%      
     filter(frag == 1, lbl == 2, lbl_z == 0) %>% 
     mutate(patrn  = 1:n(),
            patrn = paste0("a", "_",patrn)) 
  
# Extract each pick or maxes per group matching the picks on the plot
df_maxs <-
df_1 %>%
     left_join(df_2, by = c("time", "rfu")) %>%
     select(1:3,9) %>% 
     tidyr::fill(patrn) %>%
     filter(frag.x == 1) %>%
     group_by(patrn) %>%
     mutate(maxs = max(rfu)) %>%
     inner_join(df_2)

# Viz
demo %>% 
          as.tibble() %>%
          filter(time > 3000) %>% #18
ggplot(aes(x = time, y = rfu)) +
          geom_line() +
          geom_point(data = df_maxs, aes(x = time, y = maxs), col = "red") +
          geom_text(data  = df_maxs, aes(x = time, y = maxs, label = maxs), vjust = -1, col = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't pick out peaks below 3000 seconds, which is where the noise is. All the peaks need to be picked to accurately recalibrate the x-axis from seconds to base pairs. Also, this solution doesn't take into account the expected pattern of peaks (ladder below) to determine whether they are true or artifactual.  ladder <- c(50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 475, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000)

Comment: I did mention that  the solution intentionally started for fragments that was picked after 3000 seconds for clarify and demonstration ( you should be able to adjust the windows and should be able to id the picks). All the picks on this instance were accurate. However, you requirements seem to have changed, based on your last comment...